# Shift Right Register-ParallelLoad

Tags: vhdl

I have to create an n bit shift right register(used 4 bits here) with parallel load. For this purpose i used `a Mux 2 in 1` and `d flip flops`. If `load` is `'1'` then the register is loaded with a value(`DataIn)`, otherwise the register starts to shift. 
The code for the Multiplexer is:

```
entity Mux2in1onebit is
Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC;
       B : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Q : out  STD_LOGIC;
       sel : in  STD_LOGIC);
end Mux2in1onebit;

architecture Behavioral of Mux2in1onebit is
begin
Q <= A when sel = '0' else
          B;
end Behavioral
```

The code for the flip flop:

```
entity FlipFlop is
    Port ( Din : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Enable : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Reset : in  STD_LOGIC);
end FlipFlop;

architecture Behavioral of FlipFlop is
signal Qtemp : std_logic;
begin
    process(clk)  
       begin    
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            if(reset = '1') then 
                Qtemp <= '0';
            else
                if (enable = '1') then 
                    Qtemp <= Din;
                else 
                    Qtemp <= Qtemp;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
        end process ; 
    Q <= Qtemp;
end Behavioral;
```

Now in a top level module i have connected the muxs and the flip flops as following:

```
    entity ShiftRegister is
    Port ( DataIn : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           DataOut : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           Enable : in  STD_LOGIC;
              Load :in STD_LOGIC;
              BitIn : in STD_LOGIC;
              Bitout : out STD_LOGIC;
           Reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Clk : in  STD_LOGIC);
end ShiftRegister;

architecture Structural of ShiftRegister is

COMPONENT FlipFlop
    PORT(
        Din : IN std_logic;
        Enable : IN std_logic;
        Clk : IN std_logic;
        Reset : IN std_logic;          
        Q : OUT std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;
COMPONENT Mux2in1onebit
    PORT(
        A : IN std_logic;
        B : IN std_logic;
        sel : IN std_logic;          
        Q : OUT std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;

signal sigdin, sigq : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin
MBIT3: Mux2in1onebit PORT MAP(
        A => BitIn,
        B => DataIn(3),
        Q => sigdin(3),
        sel => Load
    );
BIT3: FlipFlop PORT MAP(
        Din => sigdin(3),
        Q => sigq(3),
        Enable => Enable,
        Clk => Clk,
        Reset => Reset
    );
MBIT2: Mux2in1onebit PORT MAP(
        A => sigq(3),
        B => DataIn(2),
        Q => sigdin(2),
        sel => Load
    );
BIT2: FlipFlop PORT MAP(
        Din => sigdin(2),
        Q => sigq(2),
        Enable => Enable,
        Clk => Clk,
        Reset => Reset
    );
MBIT1: Mux2in1onebit PORT MAP(
        A => sigq(2),
        B => DataIn(1),
        Q => sigdin(1),
        sel => Load
    );
BIT1: FlipFlop PORT MAP(
        Din => sigdin(1),
        Q => sigq(1),
        Enable => Enable,
        Clk => Clk,
        Reset => Reset
    );
MBIT0: Mux2in1onebit PORT MAP(
        A => sigq(1),
        B => DataIn(0),
        Q => sigdin(0),
        sel => Load
    );
BIT0: FlipFlop PORT MAP(
        Din => sigdin(0),
        Q => sigq(0),
        Enable => Enable,
        Clk => Clk,
        Reset => Reset
    );

BitOut <= sigq(0);
DataOut <= sigdin;

end Structural;
```

Now when i simulate the above code, for `reset = '1'` the flip flops are set to `0` and when `load = '1'` then the DataIn is loaded, as expected. But when `enable = '1'` the register does not shift, but i get `"0000"` as a result. Thanks.

Comment: You don't appear to have an error in the code you've displayed other than missing context clauses, a missing semicolon and DataOut connected to sigdin instead of sigq. I wrote a testbench and it appears functional. Please show your stimuli and the error.  See [sr_tb.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uU7a2.png).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Made the changes and it worked. Also, seeing your stimuli i realized that in my test bench i did not set `Enable = 1` when Load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't quite a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), missing the stimuli and actual results.

All three entity and architecture pairs were missing context clauses (`library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;`) and the architecture for Mux2in1onebit was missing a semicolon after `end Behavioral`.

After fixing those I wrote a simple testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sr_tb is
end entity;

architecture fum of sr_tb is
    signal datain:     std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "1011"; -- load value
    signal dataout:    std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal enable:     std_logic := '0';
    signal load:       std_logic := '0';
    signal bitin:      std_logic;
    signal bitout:     std_logic;
    signal reset:      std_logic := '0';
    signal clk:        std_logic := '0';
begin
DUT:
    entity work.shiftregister
        port map (
            datain => datain,
            dataout => dataout,
            enable => enable,
            load => load,
            bitin => bitin,
            bitout => bitout,
            reset => reset,
            clk => clk
        );

CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 160 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        wait for 6 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        load <= '1';
        enable <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        load <= '0';
        enable <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        bitin <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        enable <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        bitin <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        bitin <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait for 10 ns;
        bitin <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And that produced:

[image: sr_tb.png]

Which shows sigq outputs of the four flip flops are correct and points out DataOut should be assigned from sigq instead of sigdin:

```
    dataout <= sigdin;  -- should be sigq
end architecture structural;
```

If you follow `sigq(0)` in the waveform you'll see it's values are consisted with the stimuli.

From your comment to your question you were also missing `Enable` being a '1' when loading.